# tkinter text widget increasing size of frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for an application I am making and for some reason that I cannot figure out, the text widget that is inside the `message_space` frame is increasing the size of the `message_space` frame and reducing the size of the `friends_space` frame. I want the `friends_space` frame to take up 1/4th of the window size and the `message_space` frame to take up the remaining 3/4ts of the window size.

> The red is the `friends_space` frame, the blue is the `message_space` frame.

**This is how I would like the sizing of the frames to be.**

[image: Correct result]

**This is what is happening when I add the text box.**

[image: Wrong result]

> Code

```
from tkinter import *
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        master.title("PyChat")
        master.geometry("800x500")
        master.configure(bg="grey")
        master.resizable(0, 0)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.friends_space = Frame(master, bg="red")
        self.friends_space.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.chat_space = Frame(master, bg="blue")
        self.chat_space.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=NSEW)

        self.message_area = Text(self.chat_space)
        self.message_area.grid(row=0, column=0)


root = Tk()
my_gui = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `weight=` option normally controls the distribution of *extra space* beyond the minimum needed to hold the widgets in the row/column - note that the blue area to the right of the Text is exactly 3 times as wide as the red area.  You need to add a `uniform=` option, with the same value for both columns (the exact value doesn't matter) - when this is in effect, the widths are strictly in proportion to the weights.

Comment: @jasonharper I am a bit confused on where to add the `uniform=` option. I am new to tkinter.

Comment: It would go in the `.grid_columnconfigure()` calls (or `.grid_rowconfigure()`, but you don't need it there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `grid`, you divide your UI into four uniform-width columns (using the `uniform` option), then have the text widget span three.

You should also start with a small text widget that can grow into the space. Otherwise tkinter will try to preserve the large size and start removing space from the other widgets in order to try to make everything fit.

Here's an example based on your original code. However, I'm using `pack` for the text widget instead of `grid` because it requires fewer lines of code. I've also reorganized the code a bit. I find that grouping calls to `grid` together makes layout easier to grok.

I've also removed the restriction on resizing. There's rarely a good idea to limit the user's ability to resize the window. Plus, it allows you to see that the resulting UI is responsive.

```
from tkinter import *
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        master.title("PyChat")
        master.geometry("800x500")
        master.configure(bg="grey")

        master.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), uniform="uniform", weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.friends_space = Frame(master, bg="red")
        self.chat_space = Frame(master, bg="blue")

        self.friends_space.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.chat_space.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=NSEW)

        self.message_area = Text(self.chat_space, width=1, height=1)
        self.message_area.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


root = Tk()
my_gui = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```